# Spreadsheet trigger settings not disabled

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a program to send out emails via Apps script.
I have an email account in Apps script.

However, I mistakenly set up a trigger with a different account, and somehow that trigger was set up and the email is being delivered.

This problem has continued for more than 2 hours after complete removal.
We are very troubled by this issue and would appreciate an immediate response.

Comment: AFAIK a trigger in one project cannot trigger a function in another project.

Comment: What sort of trigger did you create? Time-driven triggers are not guaranteed to execute at an **exact** time ("The time may be slightly randomized", say Google). This _might_ account for a delay stopping the trigger.

Comment: `We are very troubled by this issue and would appreciate an immediate response.` It's now 9 July, but I want to clarify that StackOverflow is not responsible for the Google systems and services. StackOverflow was/is in no position to offer an "immediate response". This is/was a matter to be taken up directly with Google.